# Autowiring not working in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have tried @Autowiring in a simple springboot application. but the instance of service is coming as **null**

PFB the controller class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo9Application {
    
    @Autowired
    private static CustomerService customerService;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(customerService);
        List<CustomerDTO> listcust = customerService.fetchCustomer();
        for(CustomerDTO dto : listcust) {
            System.out.println(dto.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

PFB the service class. I have annotated with @service here

```
@Service("customerService")
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {
    //private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerServiceImpl.class);
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(CustomerServiceImpl.class);
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
```

but the service instance in controller is coming as null. Anyone can help on this ?

Comment: Are you running your app using the `main` entrypoint that you are showing us here?  If so, then of course `customerService` will be `null`.  That's the very first line of your program.  Spring has not yet had a chance to initialize itself or autowire anything.  In fact, from what I see, Spring will never be initialized as there is no code in your `main` that will cause it to be.

Comment: So in the main class I can go for application context to get bean right?

Comment: ...even if you are using a different `main` and can get Spring past its context initialization stage, I believe that the `customerService` field will still be `null` because Spring does not support `@Autowired` or `@Value` on static fields.  I know this used to be true.  Maybe they've added that feature, but I don't think so.

Comment: Generally, yes, but only after Spring has run to a certain point in its initialization.  Nothing happens in Spring unless something tells it to run.  You normally instantiate a `SpringApplication` in your `main`, and then you often call its `run` method to get Spring going.  You're not doing anything like that.

Comment: See section 4.3 of [This Spring document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html) for an example of a `main` that starts up Spring. - Are you brand new to Spring?  If so, I'd suggest finding and work through a good Spring Boot tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

*Just from the code we're able to see, there are a few visible mistakes. Chances are there might be other mistakes elsewhere that we cannot see, so I'd suggest starting over by seeing how a well-formed Spring Boot project looks like by generating one over at https://start.spring.io/.*

For what we can see, you should refactor the main method to be like the following:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(Demo9Application.class, args);
}
```

You should also remove the `static` modifier from:

```java
@Autowired
private static CustomerService customerService;
```

Finally, you can use `customerService` in a **non-static** method in `Demo9Application`, eg.:

```java
@PostConstruct
public void testDependencyInjection() {
  System.out.println(customerService); //do stuff here with your CustomerService instance
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `SpringApplication.run(Demo9Application.class, args);` as the first instruction, in your main method.

You are not running Spring Boot application, therefore, you never create Application Context (Spring Container) and you never register any bean definitions in it.

You have no container, no beans, and no means at all, for IoC functionality.

You annotate your entry-point class with `@SpringBootApplication`, but that's not enough. This alone, [enables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html):

- `@EnableAutoConfiguration`: enable Spring Boot’s auto-configuration mechanism
- `@ComponentScan`: enable @Component scan on the package where the application is located (see the best practices)
- `@Configuration`: allow to register extra beans in the context or import additional configuration classes

Popular way to *actually* bootstrap your Spring Boot application, is to invoke:

```java
SpringApplication.run(EntryPointClass.class, args);
```

Answer (score -1):

@Autowired
private static CustomerService customerService;

Remove static